# Windows WildFly Update classes and resources in IntelliJ Idea 14

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resources, wildfly

I have some trouble when I try to update classes and resources in IntelliJ Idea 14, when my project is on the Wild Fly server. If I use TomCat then I don't have this problem. Has anybody else seen this and how can I fix it? My OS is Windows, and I guess trouble is because of it.

Comment: What trouble? Error messages?

Comment: Trouble - "Update classes and resources" don't work.
No error messages.
Just doesn't update, I have to use "Redeploy"

Comment: Sorry for my english =)